# How to add a Scope's description with Spring Authorization Server?

Tags: spring-security, spring-oauth2

In [samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver/src/main/resources/templates/consent.html](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver/src/main/resources/templates/consent.html)
I find code below

```
<p class="text-primary" th:text="${scope.description}"></p>
```

But when I registered Client ,I just could add a scope's name,like this`.scope("userinfo.read")`
How can I add this scope's description like`read user's info`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a framework, Spring Authorization Server does not provide high-level features like this out of the box, but you can design them into your own application. This is what the custom consent sample you linked to has done, by providing a custom consent page.

If you check out the [controller](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/web/AuthorizationConsentController.java) for that page, you will see that the descriptions are provided by custom code. See [these lines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/3812c0e56e4786f685ac1216cd489e4690b6adf1/samples/custom-consent-authorizationserver/src/main/java/sample/web/AuthorizationConsentController.java#L85-L92).